# Custom throw new Error message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, throw

I have created my own error by extending `Error` class:

```js
class MyError extends Error
{
    constructor(message)
    {
        super(message);
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
    }
}
```

So the following code:

```js
throw new MyError('My Message');
```

will produce the following output:

```
throw new MyError('My Message')
^

MyError: My Message <-- OUR MESSAGE
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\error-meta\main.js:1:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

We can see that `My message` is printed between code line and stack trace.

How should I extend `Error` class to print `My message` or other text **before** the standart error output? So it would look like this:

```
My custom error context data!

/* ... standart error output goes here ... */
```

If this is not possible, how to completely replace standart error message?
Where it even comes from?

Important note: I want this to be displayed in unhanlded `throw`, without printing data in `catch` block!

Comment: what if you catch the error first (which allows you to print a message before any outout), and then you throw the same error inside the catch block?

Comment: @GrafiCode I am not sure how it should be written. Basically I want to throw my own errors in some places with some useful context. But now I think this can be achieved by printing fancy context message first and throwing a usual error immediately after that... I will try this approach.

Comment: yes, something like this (the rollback function does not apply in this case, but it shows how the author decided to throw the original error anyway): https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/08/error-handling-nodejs-error-classes/#real-world-example-3-not-accepting-the-error-thrown-from-an-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I extend `Error` class to print "My message" or other text before the standard error output?

You might be able to do this by overwriting the `stack` property:

```
class MyError extends Error {
    name = this.constructor.name;
    stack = 'My custom error context data!\n' + this.stack;
}
```

However, I would not recommend to do this: `.stack` isn't really standard ([yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-error-stacks)), may or may not be used by [what is actually displaying the error](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_errors.cc), and you shouldn't mess with the builtin [lazy magic getter](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/faster-stack-traces/).

> If this is not possible, how to completely replace standard error message? Where it even comes from?

It comes from the [nodejs error propagation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#error-propagation-and-interception), which just logs uncaught exceptions before terminating the process. You can override this default behaviour by adding an [`uncaughtException` event handler on `process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-uncaughtexception).

However, in the case of a CLI application, you simple shouldn't leave the exception unhandled. Catch it with `try`/`catch` around your main function, then do whatever custom error reporting you'd like to do, and call `process.exit`.

Comment: Yes. Adding `uncaughtExceptionMonitor` listener, checking whether the error is an instance of our class, display fancy messages if so and then `process.exit(1)` to prevent logging error object to console. Thank you! Honestly I never thought error mechanism in (node) JS is so... confusing.

Comment: @CMTV What's confusing about it? I'd rather say it's flexible :-) Also what kind of application do you have that cares about fancy messages for unhandled errors? Maybe the better solution would be to just *handle* them in the normal application control flow.

Comment: I find confusing being unable to fully control error message with a class extending `Error`, which requires me to hook and alter core behaviour and that is not good. As for usage, I am making a CLI tool (static site generator) and I want to print valuable context information when error appears. For example with "Missing config file" error I also print a location where it was supposed to be found and so on. I have also created a wrapper over `try {} catch` to pass additional context info when calling function from a different module.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend wrapping the whole cli script in a `try`/`catch`, instead of installing an `uncaughtException` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [stack](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errorstack) attribute from the Error class

```
class MyError extends Error{
    constructor(message){
        super('');
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
        this.stack= message +" : "+ this.stack //also you can replace this with anything you want

    }
}

throw new MyError("This is my message");
```

You will then get something like

```
This is my message : MyError
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/GummyAdmirableEvents/index.js:10:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

Comment: This is very strange but `this.stack = 'my text'` outputs `[my text] { name: 'Error' }` but `this.stack = 'my text' + this.stack;` outputs a usual error with `my text` before `MyError` but still after code line. What a weird behaviour!

Comment: Am not sure what you mean, but `this.stack = 'my text'` will outputs `my text` so basically you can set the **stack** attributes to any string you want and it will get printed when the error is thrown

Comment: On my computer Node v16.13.2 runs the exact code from your answer with `this.stack = 'my text';` and outputs `[my text] { name: 'MyError' }`

Comment: Thats weird I tried it on the same Node version and it worked as expected
here is a link to the  replit so you can try it your self https://replit.com/join/dtgrbyapof-liamssi

Answer (score 0):

I usually use it in my node projects for custom error handling like this

```
  class ApiError extends Error {
    constructor(
      statusCode,
      message = 'Something Went Wrong!',
      errors = [],
      stack = ''
    ) {
      super(message);
      this.statusCode = statusCode;
      this.data = null;
      this.message = message;
      this.success = false;
      this.errors = errors;

      if (stack) {
        this.stack = stack;
      } else {
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
      }
    }
  }

  export { ApiError };
```

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure if this is what you are seeking but you can console out your own error before the standart one like this :

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {   
      console.error(message)
      super(message);
      this.name = this.constructor.name;
  }   
}
```

Comment: This will work at first glance be eventually fail in all other cases. For example it will be printing to console when you create an instance of the error for later use. Error message is not displayed in constructor, it is displayed when you `throw` a error and this is a tricky part because I can't get **how and where exactly** error message is generated.